# latexmk being slow to compile due to an incident with feynmf

Tags: compiling, latexmk, feynmf

I once tried to use the feynmf package in a `.tex` file. It didn't work, so I never tried it again. But since then, every `.tex` document I compile using latexmk takes about 10 times longer to finish. My best guess is that the build settings of latexmk have somehow changed.

I use latexmk via latextools on Atom, which usually executes something like `latexmk -cd -e -f -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 "T2019.tex"`. The distribution I have is BasicTeX on MacOS, so I've tried...

- using latexmk via Terminal and latexmk with TeXShop
- uninstalling my distribution and its data structure [as instructed by TUG](https://www.tug.org/mactex/uninstalling.html), then reinstalling BasicTeX
- uninstalling Atom and deleting the `~/.atom` folder, then reinstalling the application
- making a blank `.latexmkrc` file in my home directory

but no change. If I use TeXShop without latexmk it is *not* slow. So is the issue with latexmk? How do I revert back to the way latexmk used to compile?

Comment: no the increased number of file access in the fls has nothing to do with latexmk or some package, that is due to  a change in latex (a future version will reduce this again). But I doubt that it would increase the latexmk compilation time so much, you perhaps have another problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've removed mention of `fls` files in my question. The problem still seems to be linked with `latexmk` in some way because TeXShop compiles fine.

Comment: You can use latexmk with TeXShop. Place the line `% !TEX program = pdflatexmk` at the top of your source file and typeset using Typeset->Typeset (Cmd-T). This actually uses an internal version of latexmk rather than the one in the TeX distribution. See if that helps. Also, do you have a latexmkrc file in the same directory as the source file(s)?

Comment: @HerbSchulz I tried just there: latexmk with TeXShop is just as slow as latexmk via Terminal or Atom. Also, I don't have a latexmkrc file in the same directory as my source file.

Comment: Have you tried to delete all auxiliary files?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes, tried that and still slow.

Comment: What version of latexmk are you using? What version of TeXShop?

Comment: Also, how large is your log file?

Comment: To follow up on Herb's comment: There's a problem with the current latexmk (4.72b).  If the log file is very big, there's a slowness in latexmk when it analyzes the log file. That will be corrected soon.  But if your log file isn't big, there's probably some other problem.

Comment: @HerbSchulz latexmk version 4.72b, TeXShop version 4.63.

Comment: @JohnCollins For a 5-page article, the log file is about 500 lines (20 KB). I've a copy of the log file of the same article compiled back when latexmk wasn't slow, and it's the same length.

Comment: Is there a way you can copy the Console output and make eit and the log file available?

Comment: @HerbSchulz see https://github.com/timchan0/T2019

Comment: At what point do you get the long wait or does everything actually long to execute? E.g., is there a long wait at the end of the pdflatex run?

Comment: @HerbSchulz when I watched the console during compiling, the longest pause is on `Transcript written on T2019.log.` and the second longest pause is on `Latexmk: Found input bbl file 'T2019.bbl'`.

Comment: This sounds like the problem with latexmk 4.72c that John Collins notes above. I know he is working on an update. You could temporarily revert to version 4.70b until that comes out.

Comment: TeXShop has been updated to version 4.64. It contains a copy of latexmk 4.73 which solves some problems that cause delays in analysing the log file. Please update  TeXShop and use its pdflatexmk engine and see if your problem goes away.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Done, now works fine! I also updated latexmk and it works fine via latextools on Atom. Can either you or John Collins post an answer so I can accept it to indicate everything's resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latexmk 4.72b took a long time to process certain log files. This problem has been corrected in latexmk 4.73.

Comment: Thank you and John Collins!